# Getting NullPointerException when trying to use an object retrieved using Iterator

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I this is my code which adds elements to ArrayList

```
if(countries==null){
  countries = new ArrayList();
  for(int x = 0; x < data.getRowCount(); x++)
  {
      String shortName = data.getString(x,0);
      String code = data.getString(x,1);
      countries.add(x, new Country(code, shortName));
  }
}
```

And following is the iterator code

```
for( Iterator iter = countries.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
{
   Country country = (Country)iter.next();
   Element optionselect = doc.createElement( "countryselect" );
   optionselect.setAttribute( "name", country.getShortName() );//Getting NULL Pointer Exception
   optionselect.setAttribute( "value", country.getCode() );
   countriesElement.appendChild( optionselect );
}
```

Now I am getting null pointer exception at line:

```
optionselect.setAttribute( "name", country.getShortName() );
```

PS: I cannot debug it as it is running on production and i cannot replicate it on local server

From the first look it looks like there is some value null in the ArrayList, but from code I cannot make out how it is possible.

Can someone shed some light on it(maybe a bug of Java 5).

EDIT: I am also getting null pointer with this code

```
List countryCodes = new ArrayList();
for (int x = 0; x < countries.size(); x++)
{
    Country c = (Country) countries.get(x);
    countryCodes.add(x, c.getCode());// Throwing Exception
}
```

This confirm one thing that there is somewhere `null` object in the `countries List`, but looking at the code I cannot see how is that possible

The stack traces are as follow:

```
Stack Trace:java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ilrn.controller.modules.Users.appendCountryList(Users.java:985)
    at com.ilrn.controller.modules.Users.setupCountries(Users.java:1348)
    at com.ilrn.controller.modules.Users.gen_add(Users.java:1329)
    at com.ilrn.controller.modules.Users.generate(Users.java:190)
    at com.ilrn.controller.ShellModule.generateShell(ShellModule.java:1958)
```

Users.java:985 is `optionselect.setAttribute( "name", country.getShortName() );`

```
Stack Trace(number 2):java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ilrn.controller.dto.IlrnCountriesDTO.getCountryCodes(IlrnCountriesDTO.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor471.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
```

Where IlrnCountriesDTO.java:45 is `countryCodes.add(x, c.getCode());`

Also please note that countries List is loaded only once(when requested first time and countries is private)

After analyzing I think this is a multi threading issue. After looking at the ArrayList code I see it is not `synchronized`(so maybe size was incremented two time for same index)

```
 public void add(int index, E element) {
    if (index > size || index < 0)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
      "Index: "+index+", Size: "+size);
  ensureCapacity(size+1);  // Increments modCount!!
  System.arraycopy(elementData, index, elementData, index + 1,
         size - index);
  elementData[index] = element;
  size++;
 }
```

this is the country class(snipet)

```
private String code_;
private String shortName_;

/**
 * Constructor sets code and short name.
 * 
 * @param code Specifies the code.
 * @param shortName Specifies the short name.
 */
public Country(String code, String shortName)
{
    code_ = code;
    shortName_ = shortName;
}
public String getCode() {
        return code_;
}

public String getShortName() {
        return shortName_;
}
```

Comment: Do *not* append things to a list while iterating over it!  You append to `countries` while iterating over its values; this may result in bizarre exceptions, or even an infinite loop.  It's hard to see how this code could possibly work in its current state.

Comment: THe check for !=null is leaking, you can try for an equal check and in the else part you can add your code

Comment: @SashiKant Leaking in what way?

Comment: @cdhowie I am not appending things while iterating, things are appended only once that too before iteration

Comment: @Ankur Ah, apparently you made an error when pasting the code then, as I see it's been updated.

Comment: Did you try a debugger to see if `country` is null?

Comment: @MiserableVariable as i said `I cannot debug it as it is running on production and i cannot replicate it on local server`

Comment: Please paste the stack trace. Is it possible that `country` is not null but `Country.getShortName()` throws `NPE`? BTW this is strange `if(countries!=null) {countries = new ArrayList();..`. You create a new list only if current is NOT null?

Comment: There are two scenarios : either "(Country)iter.next()" returns null, either "doc.createElement( "countryselect" ).

Comment: again, if `countryCodes.add(x, c.getCode())` throws NPE and `countyCodes` is not null then either `c` is null or `c.getCode()` throws NPE. Why do you not post the stacktrace?

Comment: Is countries initialization code 'accessible' by multiple threads?

Comment: @MiserableVariable posted stacktrace and also edited the question code(I posted wrong code becoz i was posting snippets as i cannot show whole code)

Comment: @mudalov see my edit I now think that might be the issue

Comment: @Anony-Mousse even if data has null value `new Country(...)` will never return null(I don't see how)

Comment: But then `countryCodes.add(x, c.getCode());` should not cause error as countryCodes is List

Answer (score 1):

Your adding code looks a little off...  You have

```
if (countries != null){
    countries = new ArrayList();
    ...
```

but shouldn't it be:

```
if (countries == null){
    countries = new ArrayList();
```

Normally, we initialise if something is null, otherwise we'd be blowing away anything that was already there.

Comment: I noted that too, but it can't cause the NPE OP is complaining about. Unless his line numbers are off and the NPE is on `countries.iterator()`