# Very odd NullPointerException while sorting

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a null pointer exception because there's some null values at the list `adPics`. It happens rarely. How is it possible?

(This code downloads images in parallel and saves them locally.)

```
List<String> downloadAdImages(List<String> imagesUrls, final String itemFolder) {
       final List adPics = new ArrayList<>();
       final ExecutorService executor = newFixedThreadPool(20);
       imagesUrls.forEach(
               picUrl -> executor.submit(() -> {
                   try {
                       String imageNewFileName = imagesUrls.indexOf(picUrl) + "." + getExtension(picUrl);
                       String bigPicUrl = picUrl.replace("b.jpg", "ab.jpg"); // big version
                       copyURLToFile(new URL(bigPicUrl), new File(itemFolder, imageNewFileName), 10, 10);
                       adPics.add(imageNewFileName);
                   } catch (IOException ex) {
                       log.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not download image {0} ({1})", new Object[]{picUrl, ex.getMessage()});
                   }
               }));
       executor.shutdown();
       try {
           executor.awaitTermination(15L, MILLISECONDS);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           log.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not wait for all images downloads");
       }
       Collections.sort(adPics); // null values at list lead to NPE here. How are there null values?
       return adPics;
   }
```

[image: Stack trace## Heading ##]

Sometimes `adPics` list has `null` values. That is the reason for the NPE. But how? Analysing the code executed in the thread, it can't be possible to add a `null` value. If there was problem downloading the image, it would thrown a IOException. `imageNewFileName` can't be `null`.

This code is Java 8 and it uses Apache Commons IO lib.

Comment: (about the question, not the downvotes) I guess it's because you are adding to a list from multiple threads, but the list is not properly synchronized.  Funny things can happen when you do that.

Comment: Are you sure the `awaitTermination` call didn't timeout, and you start sorting `adPics` while concurrently adding elements into it? No idea why that would throw a NPE but `ArrayList` isn't thread-safe so I guess anything can happen.

Comment: Hmm..  thanks @sstan I'll try using  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360401/java-synchronized-list

Comment: If it times out, I'd see the message. Still, I'll read more about that method.

Comment: @LuísSoares You wouldn't. You would see the message only if the current thread is interrupted. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit- You don't check the return value of `awaitTermination` so you don't know if it timed out or not.

Comment: It would be easy to figure out with a conditional breakpoint on `== null`, wouldn't be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is ArrayList.add(int index, E element) thread unsafe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413481/is-arraylist-addint-index-e-element-thread-unsafe)

Comment: @sstan this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Paul: I don't completely disagree with you :).  It may only be part of the problem.

Comment: Instead of posting images of text, please copy and paste the actual text into your question.  Images cannot participate in search results, they are useless to sight impaired users, and they are considerably less legible than native browser text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `awaitTermination` doesn't stop your running threads. It only waits till all threads are completed or the `timeout` is reached. Therefore your threads still adding items to your list.

Also you should consider that the download and copying to file system is running even when the timeout reached.

A simple but not perfect solution would be to set a flag when the timeout is reached and check the flag before adding more items.

A better approach would be interrupting the threads after the timeout is reached. This should also include interrupting the download and file copying.

Comment: very interesting. what would be the cleanest way to do that?

Comment: and what about people commenting about concurrent adding being the problem? Is it a mix of both problems? are they independent?

Comment: If you are using a synchronized list you will somehow masquerade your problem. It should avoid the NPE. But in the background the downloading, copying and adding is still active.  At the end your list would not be sorted for sure anymore, because new items could be still added after the sorting.

Comment: So.. what's the best way to interrupt the downloading/copying? Does that even make sense? In alternative... do you mean I should check the time passed before adding to the list?

Comment: here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File,%20int,%20int)

Comment: You are extending your class with FileUtils?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120732/discussion-between-luis-soares-and-paul-wasilewski).

Comment: *If you are using a synchronized list you will somehow masquerade your problem*. I hope you're not implying that OP should not synchronize the list.  OP should absolutely synchronize the list, but also fix the awaitTermination problem.

Comment: @sstan sure accessing a list from multiple threads should be synchronized :)

Comment: thank you! could not be better explained! Learned a lot about multi-threading now.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. Paul already pointed out one problem. Other problem is that you are accessing List adPics concurrently.

To solve your problem without using synchronized lists you could make a List[CompletableFuture] and at the end call [CompletableFuture.allOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-).
Each CompletableFuture should return image filename but before trying to download an image it should check the time to see if you want to start that operation. If not you could complete that CompletableFuture with null value.
In CompletableFuture.allOf you can make a new List without null values and sort that list.

Comment: Using a synchronized list will not solve the problem it will only masquerade the underlying issue and leads to other issues. For example the final list is not sorted for sure.

Comment: I agree, that's the reason I gave an idea how to solve it without using synchronized list.